# How can I link Azure Data Explorer to Log Analytics in code?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

In the ADX UI, I can click on "Add Cluster", paste in my Log Analytics URI, and have the Log Analytics data available for querying.  I need to be able to perform this same operation in code, and I can't find any examples of how one might accomplish this.  I would prefer this direct connection, rather than having to set up an Event Hub and export the data from Log Analytics to my ADX cluster.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please check Azure Data Explorer Proxy:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/query-monitor-data

Comment: Alexander, thanks for the reply.  That article shows the "Add Cluster" UI functionality, but I need to be able to implement the same functionality in code, so that it can be part of a AzDO Build Pipeline.

Comment: Simply use the same connection string you are using in the UI in code.